# How to change a value of object in React which will update in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a small App with and am stuck with the update section of CRUD.

1. Array of objects:

```
    vehicles = [{
    "id": "-NXfnDLxUbeX1JUNaTJY",
    "title": "Chevrolet",
    "subtitle": "C3500",
    "imgSrc": "...",
    "description": "The fourth generation of the C/K series is a range of trucks that was manufactured by General Motors.",
    "color": "grey"
}, {
    "id": "-NXg3rkWSfsFIul_65su",
    "title": "Volkswagen",
    "subtitle": "Passat",
    "imgSrc": "...",
    "color": "yellow"
}, {
    "id": "-NXgPWOCSoXfKQuM4IHP",
    "title": "Peugeot",
    "subtitle": "208",
    "imgSrc": "...",
    "description": "The Peugeot 208 is a supermini car (B-segment in Europe) produced by the French automaker Peugeot.",
    "color": "white"
}
```

2. This is my VehicleCard styled component

```
<VehicleCardWrapper>
        <Link to={`/vehicle${url}`}>
          <VehicleCardFigure>
            <VehicleCardImage src={imgSrc} alt={imgAlt} />
          </VehicleCardFigure>
          <VehicleCardTitle>{title}</VehicleCardTitle>
          <VehicleCardSubtitle>{subtitle}</VehicleCardSubtitle>
        </Link>
        <div>
          <Button isSecondary onClick={editVehicle}>
            Edit
          </Button>
          <Button isSecondary onClick={deleteHandler}>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </div>
      </VehicleCardWrapper>
```

3. This is a Grid component that renders vehicles. I have three of them and they are working just fine.

```
<Grid>
      {vehicles.map((vehicle) => (
        <VehicleCard
          url={vehicle.id}
          key={vehicle.id}
          imgSrc={vehicle.imgSrc}
          title={vehicle.title}
          subtitle={vehicle.subtitle}
          editVehicle={() => editVehicle(vehicle.id)}
     
        />
      ))}
    </Grid>
```

This is how I started writing a function

```
    const editVehicle = (key) => {
    console.warn("function called", vehicles.key);
  };
```

- result in console.log is "undefined".

How can I select only one vehicle, the one that is inside the VehicleCard component?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs a little formatting. Note; [here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the function ***editVehicle***. You already pass the vehicle *id* as your first argument and than on the function itself you try to access the *vehicles.key* property which does not exist, hence the 'undefined' log.

Simply change the function to the following:

```js
 const editVehicle = (key) => {
    console.warn("function called", key);
  };
```

You will be able to see the *id* of the individual vehicle that you are trying to edit.